# apache serverName which not correspond name folder of site

Tags: apache, apache2.4

So, querstion:
I have the following file structure

```
domains
  - learn
    - symfonyblog
      - web
```

I need to have hostname -> symfonyblog, and save the file structure, that I had. How can I do it?
I've tried to do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot    "c:\openServer\domains\Learn\symfonyblog\web"
    ServerName      "Learn"
    <Directory "c:\openServer\domains\Learn\symfonyblog\web">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work. The decision that I found is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot    "c:\openServer\domains\symfonyblog\web"
    ServerName      "symfonyblog"
    <Directory "c:\openServer\domains\symfonyblog\web">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But this example doesn't contain needed file structure.
Tell me please how to solve such problem?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, it's not a problem if the "ServerName" doesn't correspond with the name folder of the website. The "ServerName" must match the name of the website you type in the URL. Example :

Comment: I want to access to my webapp with : http://symfonywebapp.com then I set 'ServerName symfonywebapp.com' in apache configuration

Comment: It was difficult for me to named this issue. If you can names it better - do it. About problem: I can't make path in of VH in subfolder. E.g. I can make normally in next file structure (FS) domains/symfonyBlog any pathes, but can't make if FS is domain/Learn/SymfonyBlog. In last way I can't give it serverName SymfonyBlog. Doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: You can give ServerName SymfonyBlog, then you must have a resolution name (CNAME, host file, whatever) of SymfonyBlog

Comment: Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html